# Генерация случайных чисел в диапазоне параметров функции

Tags: javascript

Есть задача, нужно написать функцию с параметрами min, max, которая генерирует случайное число с плавающей точкой от min до max (но не включая max). Пытаюсь использовать Math.random, но не знаю как ему задать диапазон значений, так как он только от 0 выводит

Answer (score 1):

Вот [тут](https://schoolsw3.com/js/js_random.php) есть немного разных функций простых

А я долгое время пользуюсь этим:

```js
const rand=(min,max=min+10)=>(Math.floor(min+Math.random()*(max+1-min)));
```

А для float:

```js
const randFloat=(min=0, max=1)=>{
    min = min > max ? [max, max = min][0] : min;
    return (min+Math.random()*(max-min));
};
```

Comment: Второй какой-то стремный, или я не так его понял... если min больше max, min присваивается max, а max присваивается min... почему бы не `if( min > max ) min = max;` ?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME это смена значений двух переменных без третей, на случай перестановки значений, можно удалить, я из пакета копипастнул

Comment: Возможен и такой вариант `if( min > max ) [min, max] = [max, min];`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME действительно, работает, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

> Пытаюсь использовать Math.random, но не знаю как ему задать диапазон значений, так как он только от 0 выводит

В интьерньетах встречал такие перлы: `Math.random() * (1 - 0) + 0`

Поэтому, чтобы не было никакой "магии", на пальцах:

Скажем, нужно случайное целое число от 10 до 15 не включительно.

`Math.random()` возвращает случайное число в диапазоне `[0, 1)` — не включая `1`

Если умножить число на 5, оно будет диапазон `[0, 5)`

Добавить +10, станет `[10, 15)`, остается полученное число округлять вниз:

`Math.floor( Math.random() * 5 + 10 )` // 10, 11, 12, 13, 14

10 — это ваш `min`

а 5 — `max - min`

Оттуда и получается

`Math.floor( Math.random() * (max - min) + min )`

Answer (score 0):

В документации Math.random:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

есть нужный вам пример:

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```